# Subpartitions? FAT32 Hidden partition? I never created them

Tags: linux, partitioning, gparted

I try to make bootable a Linux partition on a USB, equipped with GRUB (GRUB2 I think).
But I had the surprise to see subpartitions that I never tried to create. How did they come here?
I just wanted an extended partition with 2 logical partitions (they are not *sub*partitions, I'll explain later).

My partition structure, as shown by *Gparte*d, is:

┌------------┐

. . .  sdb1
*extended*
298.09 Gio
└------------┘

└──  dev/sdb5   ext4 label: Partition-1  size: 148.45 Gio used: 3.38 Gio free: 147.05 Gio
└──  dev/sdb6   ext4 label: Partition-2  size: 149.64 Gio used: 16.83 Gio free: 132.80 Gio

and Gparted says (when using cut & paste):

```
Disque /dev/sdb5 : 148,5 GiB, 159396134912 octets, 311320576 secteurs
Unités : sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 octets
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x20ac7dda
```

But when I run fdisk, to test if I can make sdb5 bootable this way (I should probably only edit the GRUB) it shows weird surprises:

```
fdisk -l /dev/sdb5   
Périphérique Amorçage      Start        Fin   Secteurs   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb5p1           3224498923 3657370039  432871117 206,4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb5p2           3272020941 5225480974 1953460034 931,5G 16 **FAT16** **masquée**
/dev/sdb5p3                    0          0          0     0B 6f inconnu
/dev/sdb5p4             50200576  974536369  924335794 440,8G  0 Vide
```

"masquée" means "hidden", "inconnu" means "unknow", and "vide" means "void, empty".

- How these strange sdb5p1, p2, p3, came? Looks like sub-partitions, or something like that, it's the first time I see this.
- Why there's a hidden one in FAT32. I've nerver created that.

I created sdb1, sdb5 and sdb6 on the USB disk using Gparted to
formatted format & create.

Comment: _Why_ are you running fdisk against a partition?

Comment: It shows partition info that I needed in the command line.